# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't show any fonts on Arch Linux, GNOME3

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate via Jetbrains Toolbox.
Then I ran it ant it doesn't show any fonts like this.

[image: screenshot]

I'm using GNOME3 on Antergos(Arch Linux). System font is "Noto Sans CJK JP Medium".
Please tell me if any other information is needed.

Comment: please raise a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues with idea.log attached.

Comment: Moved here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198790

Answer (score 0):

If you using last version IntelliJ IDEA you shouldn't have this problem, but you have it you can use this command: **export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on** or **export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not working for me :(